# Does C# null conditional operator make any difference in calling an async task?

Tags: c#

Is there any difference between

```
await myObject.fooAsync();
```

and

```
await myObject?.fooAsync();
```

They seem to throw the same exception when myObject is null: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Apparently _myObject_ is null. You cannot call null as a function. Just my five cents :)

Comment: That's basically the same as `await (myObject == null ? (Task)null : myObject.fooAsync())`.  And awaiting will try to call methods on that `Task`, thus the errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> They seem to throw the same exception when myObject is null: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Sure, but for different reasons.

When you use the null-conditional operator, the expression it's involved with will evaluate to null if any element where the operator is applied is null.

When you don't use the operator, you get a `NullReferenceException`, because you can't call `fooAsync()` on a null reference. When you do use the operator, you get the same exception but this time because you can't await a null reference.

The moral of the story: you can't just sprinkle `?.` around in your code and expect it to become null-safe. That's not what it does. It's just a short-hand for commonly-used null-related expressions. You still have to worry about null references, because the null-conditional operator can itself generate null references.

Comment: _you can't just sprinkle ?. around in your code and expect it to become null-safe._ might print that out and out and stick it on a co-worker’s desk. He’s put me right off the entire feature by constantly (and lazily) abusing it.